# How does Floyd-Warshall alogirthm gurantee shortest path?

Tags: algorithm

Self-learning coding here, and I am having trouble wrapping my head around this one, so I would really appreciate it if someone could explain this as simply as possible.

Basically my issue is I am not sure how the Floyd Warshall algorithm is definitely able to give the shortest path possible, why do cases as I am going to describe below not happen at all?

Consider the following connections:

A to B,

B to C,

C to D,

D to E.

Perhaps in finding A to E, we might be unable to find a route because the connection from B to D wasn't established yet? Of course this example is very simple and can be traced by hand how the algorithm works, but how do we know for sure that previous required connections were already made, so that the new connections can be found? Such as when there are hundreds of vertices, and each one has more than one connection to others??

I am sure it has something to do with the outermost loop, k, looping as many times as there are vertices.

I also found this on wikipedia which I think could be the explanation, but i don't really understand it.

> For each of these pairs of vertcies, the shortestpath(i, j, k) could
>   be either
>
> (1) a path that does not go through k (only uses vertcies in the set
>   {1, ..., k-1}.)
>
> or
>
> (2) a path that does go through k (from i to k and then from k to j,
>   both only using intermediate vertices in {1, ..., k-1})

Comment: Nonetheless, the explanation you quote is the explanation why the algorithm works. Note that it doesn't just loop as many times as there are vertices. Rather, it systematically explores each vertext in turn. At each loop, one vertex is removed from consideration.

Comment: (Your spelling checker doesn't seem to cover the title. And there still is a transposition in `vertcies` in more than one place.)